# Tkinter: How to add kwargs to a class you inherit from?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

How do I add keyword arguments ([**options](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm)) to a Tkinter class that inherits from `tk.Frame`? For example, all I want to do is set the frame's `width` and `height` (or any other options).

The broader question is: how do I add **kwargs to the object the class itself inherits from?

```
class profiles(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    self.parent = parent
    kwargs['width'] = 900
    kwargs['height'] = 600
    super(profiles, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Edit**:

Here's a complete code example of what I'm trying to understand. This is the entire code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class profiles(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    self.parent = parent
    kwargs['width'] = 900
    kwargs['height'] = 600
    kwargs['background'] = 'red'
    #tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    super(profiles, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

    #self.parent.geometry('900x600')

    self.profile_name_label = tk.Label(self.parent, text='Profile name:')
    self.profile_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(20), pady=20)

    self.ProfileNameVar = tk.StringVar()
    self.profile_name_entry = tk.Entry(self.parent, textvariable=self.ProfileNameVar)
    self.profile_name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(20))

root = tk.Tk()
profiles(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Questions about this code:

1. `self.parent.geometry('900x600')` does what I expect which is resizing the window. **Should kwargs['width'] = 900 and kwargs['height'] = 600 do the same thing Since `tk.Frame` sits inside its parent `root`?** It seems like none of the `kwargs` I add do anything.
2. Even if I add `kwargs['background'] = 'red'`, I see no effect. I've seen examples of people using this syntax: [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2006-August/048394.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459993/tkinter-listbox-drag-and-drop-with-python/25023944#25023944). **Why doesn't the background color turn red?**

[image: picture of tkinter window]

Comment: So in effect you're always forcing the height and width?

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Just add what you want to add directly, without adding it to `kwargs`:

```
class profiles(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, width=900, height=800, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: If `width` or `height` are already present in `kwargs` this will cause duplicate argument errors

Answer (score 0):

You would do it like this:

```
class Profiles(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        kwargs.update(width=900, height=600)
        super(profiles, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
```

This will override the keywords if they were passed in the call to `Profiles()`. Additional logic would be required to avoid that.